# Beginner: Importing CSV to D3

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I just started using D3/JS. I'm working off a chord diagram [template](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062006) and am having trouble importing my csv.

The template uses:

```
 var matrix = [[data...],[data...],[data...],[data...]]
```

My data is in a csv with no headings:

```
 124, 232, 412, 152
 521, etc
 ...
 ...
```

I've been perusing stackoverflow and d3 api but I'm clearly missing something... probably really simple. Of the things I've tried, they look something like:

```
d3.csv("test.csv", function(matrix) {
    //the template code//
});
```

some suggested using d3.text and d3.parserows, is that where i should be looking?

Thanks!

Comment: Ah I think it had to do w/ chrome at a cross origin request problem (which I will now look into, as I have little clue what that means).

Comment: How are you testing this? Are you trying to do it offline just from a file on your browser? If you are, that's the reason you're getting the cross-origin request problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as this.

```
d3.text('spreadsheet.csv', function(error, _data){
            var table = d3.csv.parseRows(_data);
        });
```

Or here's an alternative using `jquery-csv` if you want:

```
<script src="jquery-csv.js"></script>

var table = $.csv.toArrays("spreadsheet.csv");
```